# how can we rotate the texture drawn for a image in the open gl project using objective c?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am drawing the image on an opengl view using

```
[Texture2D_plane drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(_position.x,_position.y)];
```

But after a certain point, I want to make the rotation of the texture.
What function I have to use for it?

From somewhere I use:

```
glRotatef(90,_position.x,_position.y,0);
```

But I don't know how to use it, I just want to make rotation of my texture image of at 90degree.
Is this function helpful or I have to use another way to rotate it.

Any code or link?

Here it is my draw at point method implementation

```
- (void) drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point 
{
GLfloat     coordinates[] = { 0,    _maxT,
    _maxS,  _maxT,
    0,      0,
_maxS,  0 };
GLfloat     width = (GLfloat)_width * _maxS,
height = (GLfloat)_height * _maxT;
GLfloat     vertices[] = {  -width / 2 + point.x,   -height / 2 + point.y,  0.0,
    width / 2 + point.x,    -height / 2 + point.y,  0.0,
    -width / 2 + point.x,   height / 2 + point.y,   0.0,
width / 2 + point.x,    height / 2 + point.y,   0.0 };

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _name);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

This is the implementation of the draw at point

Comment: What type is `Texture2D_plane`? And what does its `drawAtPoint` function look like?

Comment: Texture2D_plane = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spaceship.png"]];
i am creating an image texture like this one !!!

Comment: What does the Texture2D class look like? What is the implementation of the `drawAtPoint` function?

Comment: i have shown how i implement the draw at point method is any other function for rotating the texture in opengles